# ASP.NET Boilerplate .NET Core 2

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, aspnetboilerplate

Trying to upgrade `ASP.NET Boilerplate` project from `.NET Core 1.x` to `.NET Core 2.0`

Solution builds successfully, but throws exception in `Startup.ConfigureServices` method at

```
 services.AddAbpIdentity<Tenant, User, Role, SecurityStampValidator>(
     options => {})
   .AddUserManager<UserManager>()
   .AddRoleManager<RoleManager>()
   .AddSignInManager<SignInManager>()
   .AddClaimsPrincipalFactory<UserClaimsPrincipalFactory>()
   .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Exception details

> System.TypeLoadException: 'Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SharedAuthenticationOptions' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60'.'

Comment: Have you already tried to follow this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/

Comment: @PeterB Yeah, i updated all the packages to `2.0` version, but same error.

Comment: update for Core2 is coming soon...

Comment: Roadmap links: https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/issues/243

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should wait ABP v3.0. We have released ABP v3.0.0-beta2. If you want, you can use beta version.

You also need to change your solution for:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x

Fortunately, I upgraded solution template. So, you can see all changes I done:

https://github.com/aspnetboilerplate/module-zero-core-template/pull/106/files

Comment: Have you an idea about the release date for the v3?